# Error using gzip self._read(readsize) with some larger files 220 meg

Tags: python

Hi I am trying to unzip Landsat 7 gap mask using this code

```
file_z='C:/bassel300\gap_mask\LE717_B8.TIF.gz'
inF = gzip.GzipFile(file_z, 'rb')
s = inF.read()
inF.close()
```

the code will work with all bands except band 8 which is the pan and larger in size (220 meg) than other bands (55 meg)

This is the error I get:

```
Unhandled exception while debugging...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\test22\bnd8.py", line 9, in <module>
    s = inF.read()
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\gzip.py", line 245, in read
    self._read(readsize)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\gzip.py", line 304, in _read
    self._add_read_data( uncompress )
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\gzip.py", line 322, in _add_read_data
    self.extrabuf = self.extrabuf[offset:] + data
MemoryError
>>>
```

Comment: It looks like a *Memory error*... Uncompressing 220 Mb in memory is likely to give that except if you have plenty of memory, and all the decompressing chain is 64 bits. Do you really need to process everything in memory?

Comment: Unzip the file to a new file using a standalone tool.  That will tell you how big it is.